# Keep original precision in dataframes during calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, precision

I am a bit confused about how python store values and how I should keep the original precision.
My problem is that after some calculation, I got a dataframe which contains `Inf` and `NaN`.
Then I replicate the same steps in Excel. The strange thing is that I got specific numbers in Excel for the NaN/Inf cases in python, but all other values are the same.

The calculation involves division, and whenever I encountered a very small number, for example, `2.48065E-16` in Excel, I got `0.0` in Python.
So I tried `df = df.round(20)` at the very beginning, the `NaN` disappeared, but I still got `Inf`.
I also tried `pd.set_option('float_format', '{:f}'.format)` but it didn't work.

Any idea on how I should let python store and manipulate the values in dataframes without changing the original precision?

Comment: Have you tried casting to float64? `dataframe.your_data_column.astype('float64')`

Comment: @meti Thank you for your comment, but I think the data types are already `float64` in my dataframe at the very beginning (`df.dtypes` returns `float64` for all columns). Any other ideas on how to get rid of the Inf and let it be the same as the value in Excel?

Comment: Can you post the code that did 2.48065E-16 ==> 0.0.  I's suspect Excel before python. precision on floats is a function of the value, it is not constant across the range.